# Draw a circle of unknown radius using ruler-compass construction

Tags: circles, geometric-construction

Imagine a circle A of unknown radius, its tangent line passes through another circle B center. The distance between A's point of tangency and B's center is known (but not measured). B's radius is also known (but not measured). Circle B and the tangent line are already drawn on the paper.

Using only a compass and straight edge, how do I draw circle A such that it just touches circle B?

Comment: This is not clear.  What data is given?  What do you want to construct?

Comment: @lulu I want to create/draw circle A so that it fits the descriptions above. The aformentioned distance and circle B's radius is defined on the paper.

Comment: If $x$ is the radius of $A$, $d$ is the distance between the point of tangency of $A$ and $B$'s center and $r$ the radius of $B$, then by Pythagoras $x^2+d^2=(x+r)^2$. Therefore, $x=\frac{a^2-r^2}{2r}=\frac{(a+r)(a-r)}{2r}$. So, you only need to compute the fourth proportional of $a+r, a-r$ and $2r$. You can do this by drawing [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) picture for these three lengths. Once you have $x$ extend a radius of $B$ beyond the circle $x$ units and there is the center of $A$. There is one solution for each radius of $B$.

Comment: @lulu - I think you want to draw a circle A tangential to B which has the property that  one of A's tangent lines passes through B's center with the given distance.

Comment: @lulu but they might not be the right distance

Comment: @Henry  Got it.  The description starts by saying "Given a circle $A$", but the OP does not mean that.

Comment: In my comment above there is another case to consider, the case that $a<r$. In that case the circle $A$ must be inside $B$. The formula changes to $x^2+d^2=(r-x)^2$.

Comment: @lulu I meant that circle B and the tangent line of A are already drawn. I don't have the exact values.

Comment: If the tangent line is already drawn, then you can mark the given distance between the tangency point and the center of $B$ on it. Lift a perpendicular to the line at that point. Compute $x$ as above and mark length $x$ on the perpendicular. That gives you the center of $A$. There are two solutions in that case, depending on what side of the perpendicular you mark the distance $x$.

Comment: I've edited the description as it was unclear. Apologies.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy  You are not supposed to do any computing. This is an exercise in construction.

Comment: @YNK Read my comment completely. Besides, if you know anything about Greek mathematics you would know that computing and constructing are just the same thing. It is absurd what you are saying "Not do X, do Y", when X and Y are the same thing.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Yes, I did not read your 1st comment carefully. I apologize. But I don't agree that computing and constructing is the same in any geometry. Besides, now you have the solution, Please post it as an answer with your construction.

Comment: @YNK It doesn't matter if you agree or not. It is, independently of what you think. I already posted the answer, won't be copying it anywhere else.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\bf\rm{Fig. 1}$ shows what is given. $O_B$ is the center of the circle-B and $T$ is the point of tangency. The line $O_BT$ meets the circumference of the circle-B at $E$. It is assumed that the radius of the circle-B = $b$ and $O_bT=d$.

As MoonLightSyzygy pointed out in one of his comments, there are two different solutions to your problem, one is when $d\gt b$ and the other is when $d\lt b$. The difference is elucidated by the fact that the circles A and B of the former solution are touching externally and those of the latter touche each other internally. However, the 6-step recipe of the construction for both cases are the same. I also guarantee that the solutions given below are pure constructions and include no computing whatsoever.

$\bf\rm{Fig. 2}$ illustrates the construction of externally contacting circles in its entirety.

$\bf\rm{Step\space 1:}$ Draw the perpendicular to $TO_B$ at $T$. The center of the circle-A lies on this line.

$\bf\rm{Step\space 2:}$ Extend $TO_B$ to meet the circle-B again at $F$. Note that $TF=d+b$.

$\bf\rm{Step\space 3:}$ Draw an arc with radius $TE$ and center $T$ to intersect the perpendicular constructed
$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ in $\rm{Step\space 1}$ at $G$. Note that $TG=d-b$.

$\bf\rm{Step\space 4:}$ Draw a straight line joining $F$ and $G$ to cut the circlr-B at $H$

$\bf\rm{Step\space 5:}$ Join $O_B$ to $H$ and then extend this line to meet the perpendicular constructed
$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ in $\rm{Step\space 1}$ at $O_A$.

$\bf\rm{Step\space 6:}$ Draw the circle with radius $O_AH$ and center at $O_A$. This is the circle-A.

Since the case $d\lt b$ is construction-wise the same (see $\bf\rm{Fig. 3}$), it is not described here. I would like to let you figure out what happens when $d=b$. Now, the story does not end here, because someone (not me) has to rake his or her brain to prove the construction I described above. Happy hunting!

Comment: @Gregory Leo Have you been able to  prove or find a proof of the construction?